# docker-compose up is failing becuase of COPY conf.d/* /etc/nginx/conf.d is not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have `Dockerfile` that does:

```
COPY conf.d/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

and in my `nginx.conf` i am including this from the same directory in my docker image:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
```

But, when I want to `docker-compose up` it is failing, because of this line in nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
```

And the error is:

> 2019/07/17 14:07:35 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:14

I made sure that I have conf.d folder and inside this folder I have following files:
 1. default.conf
 2. ssl.conf 
 3. header.conf

My whole `Dockerfile`:

```
# https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/stable/alpine
# https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

FROM alpine:3.8

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.14.1
ENV NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION 1.2.1

RUN GPG_KEYS=B0F4253373F8F6F510D42178520A9993A1C052F8 \
    && CONFIG="\
        --prefix=/etc/nginx \
        --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
        --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
        --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
        --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
        --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
        --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
        --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
        --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
        --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
        --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
        --user=nginx \
        --group=nginx \
        --with-http_ssl_module \
        --with-http_realip_module \
        --with-http_addition_module \
        --with-http_sub_module \
        --with-http_dav_module \
        --with-http_flv_module \
        --with-http_mp4_module \
        --with-http_gunzip_module \
        --with-http_gzip_static_module \
        --with-http_random_index_module \
        --with-http_secure_link_module \
        --with-http_stub_status_module \
        --with-http_auth_request_module \
        --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-threads \
        --with-stream \
        --with-stream_ssl_module \
        --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
        --with-stream_realip_module \
        --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_slice_module \
        --with-mail \
        --with-mail_ssl_module \
        --with-compat \
        --with-file-aio \
        --with-http_v2_module \
    " \
    && addgroup -S nginx \
    && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx nginx \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        gcc \
        libc-dev \
        make \
        openssl-dev \
        pcre-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        linux-headers \
        curl \
        gnupg1 \
        libxslt-dev \
        gd-dev \
        geoip-dev \
    && curl -fSL https://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz -o nginx.tar.gz \
    && curl -fSL https://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz.asc  -o nginx.tar.gz.asc \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && found=''; \
    for server in \
        ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net \
        hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
        hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
        pgp.mit.edu \
    ; do \
        echo "Fetching GPG key $GPG_KEYS from $server"; \
        gpg --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$GPG_KEYS" && found=yes && break; \
    done; \
    test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch GPG key $GPG_KEYS" && exit 1; \
    gpg --batch --verify nginx.tar.gz.asc nginx.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" nginx.tar.gz.asc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src \
    && tar -zxC /usr/src -f nginx.tar.gz \
    && rm nginx.tar.gz \
  \
  # Nginx RTMP Module
    && CONFIG="$CONFIG --add-module=/usr/src/nginx-rtmp-module-$NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION " \
  && curl -fSL https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/archive/v$NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION.tar.gz -o nginx-rtmp-module.tar.gz \
  && tar -zxC /usr/src -f nginx-rtmp-module.tar.gz \
    && rm nginx-rtmp-module.tar.gz \
  \
    && cd /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
    && ./configure $CONFIG --with-debug \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && mv objs/nginx objs/nginx-debug \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && ./configure $CONFIG \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && rm -rf /etc/nginx/html/ \
    && mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d/ \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m644 html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m644 html/50x.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m755 objs/nginx-debug /usr/sbin/nginx-debug \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && ln -s ../../usr/lib/nginx/modules /etc/nginx/modules \
    && strip /usr/sbin/nginx* \
    && strip /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
  \
  # Remove temp directory for rtmp module
  && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx-rtmp-module-$NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION \
    \
    # Bring in gettext so we can get `envsubst`, then throw
    # the rest away. To do this, we need to install `gettext`
    # then move `envsubst` out of the way so `gettext` can
    # be deleted completely, then move `envsubst` back.
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .gettext gettext \
    && mv /usr/bin/envsubst /tmp/ \
    \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so /tmp/envsubst \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )" \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .nginx-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && apk del .gettext \
    && mv /tmp/envsubst /usr/local/bin/ \
    \
    # Bring in tzdata so users could set the timezones through the environment
    # variables
    && apk add --no-cache tzdata \
    \
    # forward request and error logs to docker log collector
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/yuz1.org
COPY cert/* /etc/letsencrypt/live/yuz1.org/

RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types
COPY conf.d/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 1047
EXPOSE 1935

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And my whole `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

}
```

My whole `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  app:
    image: gcr.io/bounce-code/nodes/proxy-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      publicnet:
        aliases:
          - internal.yuz1.org
          - dev.yuz1.org
          - yuz1.org
      servicenet:
        aliases:
          - proxy.node.internal.yuz1.org
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 1047:1047
      - 1935:1935
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

networks:
  servicenet:
    name: yuz1-servicenet
  publicnet:
    name: yuz1-publicnet
```

My folder structure: 
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCuVz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sits on the wildcard symbol on your `COPY` instruction, in a Dockerfile if you want to copy the entire folder you have to target the folder itself, otherwise, everything after the `/` gets interpreted as a file.

Also, your `conf.d` folder should sit on the same level of the Dockerfile and it is included in the context sent to your container (and not listed on your `.dockerignore` file)

This should appropriately copy the files of the local project `conf.d` directory up to your container's folder:

```
COPY ./conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: unfortunately problem persists

Comment: Does the `conf.d` folder sit in the same context you're sending to the container?

Comment: yes in the same directory: 
you can see my folder strucuter
here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCuVz.png